# Is it possible to answer "te abrazo también"

Tags: gramática

If someone says to you: "*te abrazo*" and you want to answer simply "[hug] *you too*", can you answer in Spanish the following: "*te también*"?

Or my versions below would be more correct:

"*Igualmente*"

"*A ti también*"

Or natives would most likely respond even with full version "*te abrazo también*"?

Comment: First "te abrazo" sounds weird. Could you be talking about "¿te abrazo?" as a question?. If it is so then an answer would be simply "si" or "claro (que si)". "Te abrazo" means "I hug you" that for me sound weird in english too.

Comment: I mean exactly "I hug you", not in question form. Actually, heard sometimes in informal speech people saying ór writing (in chat, for example) "hug you''.

Comment: So in Spanish it would be "un abrazo" which means "I'm sending you a hug"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most common ways to respond to

> Te abrazo

would be

> Yo a ti también
>
> Y yo a ti
>
> Igualmente

But *te abrazo* is uncommon in many areas. A more common sentence to send a hug to someone is

> Un abrazo

to which you would respond with

> Igualmente
>
> A ti también

The sentence <del>*te también*</del> is gramatically incorrect.

Comment: "Te abrazo" sounds weird to me. I guess the question is about «¿Te abrazo?» as a question and then an answer to that would be more like "si" instead. Don't you think?

Comment: Good you added "un abrazo". The OP might be thinking about that one instead

Comment: @DGaleano I assumed the OP is referring to *un abrazo*, I am not completely sure. I have now clarified that *te abrazo* is not common with that meaning.

Comment: I agree wimi. "Un abrazo" is very common while I've never heard anyone saying "te abrazo" but I'm aware of regional differences so it might be used somewhere. +1

Comment: I agree but it's pretty easy to fix: *Te doy un abrazo*.  The reciprocal response is, as wimi suggested, "Y yo a tí."